# How to replace a git submodule with the contents of the submodule?

Tags: git, git-submodules

On a company project we used a submodule for a while but it caused issues again and again. Our decision was to remove the submodule and copy all files of the submodule into the folder where the submodule was. (This is required because we have an old build system which requires the files in that folder.

So I made the changes:

```bash
cp -r build/sub ../sub
git rm -f build/sub
mv ../sub build/sub
rm build/sub/.git
```

That worked on my machine and on the build system too. But a co-worker tried to pull the changes and got: `The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge`.
After the pull we tried `git fetch --all && git reset --hard origin/master`, which did not fail but it did not work either. We don't have the error messages anymore but it failed to remove the build/sub folder because it was not empty but git proceeded.
It copied almost all files into the build/sub folder but it did not remove the submodule itself. So the .git file was still in the build/sub folder but the subdmodule was remove from the .gitmodules file.

So... I am not sure how to continue here without breaking the repositories of my colleagues. How can I replace the submdoule with the contents of the submodule but without breaking stuff?

Comment: Sorry, good point. We used --hard, I typed the commands above manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use this:
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#Documentation/git-submodule.txt-deinit-f--force--all--ltpathgt82308203

It's not enough to manually delete parts of your working directory/tree (subdirectory).
You must tell git that the submodule should no longer exist in the repository. So that git can abandon the submodule, and delete it.

Just like when you add a repository: you don't copy and paste the content, you configure a submodule in git, then let git update the contents of the subdirectory.

Comment: The most important thing is to not use the "backdoor" of your file system. Use git functions to abandon the submodule instead of just deleting the directory.
If my answer solved your problem, please indicate it as the solution as well.
If you have more questions regarding this or need extra clarification, do feel free to reach out.

Comment: Yes, actually I thought I did by using git rm and readding it as new. 

Yes, I'll do it as soon as I tested it.

Comment: I understand, that would have worked for simple files (if I understand the documentation correctly). But with submodules, everything is different and all actions should happen using "git submodule" commands.
I have more experience using a graphical user interface, but I know the general principle of submodules using the command line and that every action on the submodules is a "git submodule" command...

Comment: It looks good so far. Some of my colleagues are on vacation so I have to wait for more tests. But still, I had to add the files manually again, since deinit just cleared the submodule folder. Effectively I ran git deinit -f -- build/sub && git rm -r build/sub && rm .gitmodules and then I copied the files to build/sub again.

Comment: Hi Apollo, I'm glad you are happy with the results so far (or at least with parts of it).
It is correct that deinit will only remove the submodule and the content ('working tree' is the word used in the git documentation). Manually adding the content of the repository to you project, seems normal to me. Git cannot do that for you. Be sure to use the version (commit) of the submodule repository that you are interested in when you copy the files to the empty directory.

Comment: From your original answer I thought that was the case. What seems odd to me is that I have to remove the entry (or the whole) .gitmodules manually. I checked if there is any command but I have not found one.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you mean by "I have to remove the .gitmodules manually"? Do you mean you commit an updated .gitmodules file in your parent git repository?

Comment: After running git submodule deinit it removed the submodule entries from .git/config, but the submodule information in .gitmodules remained.

Comment: I see, I must admit that I did not expect this behaviour, but in this section of the documentation, the effects/results of deinit and rm are described: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitsubmodules#_forms and this seems to be normal.
I think this link will set you on your way to finding the perfect solution for your particular use case.

Comment: The colleague who had the most issues with git and especially the submodule has tested it without any issues. It worked. Thanks for your answer, I marked it as solution.